Automatically maximizing Mate-Terminal when launched
I'm using Ubuntu-Mate 24.04. I am severely visually impaired, and cannot use a mouse. I'm strictly using the Orca screen reader, so keep that in mind that telling me to point and click on things is not going to be possible; I must do everything with keyboard shortcuts.
Upon pressing CTRLALTT, I am perfectly aware when the terminal opens, that I can press ALTSpace followed by the letter X to maximize the window. However, what I'm wanting to do is, I want it so that when I hit ALTCTRLT, the terminal window is already in a maximized state instead of a restored state.
I assume there's a really easy way to make this happen, but I can't for the life of me seem to figure it out.
Help please?

The requirement of being able to change the shortcut using the command line makes this kinda difficult to accomplish.

One way would be to create a custom Ctrl+Alt+T shortcut that will override the default Ctrl+Alt+T shortcut; this is easily done using the GUI, but is not as easily done using the command line (it'd require scripting / handling already existing shortcuts correctly);
Another way would be to override the command run by the run-command-terminal action in org.mate.Marco.global-keybindings (which is the command that is invoked when hitting Ctrl+Alt+T). IIRC (and looking around using DConf-Editor seems to confirm this), the command is harcoded somewhere and cannot be changed by simply modifying the schema.

However, if you're willing to settle for an alternate solution, there's a command under org.mate.Marco.keybinding-commands (command-4) which is set by default to x-terminal-emulator (i.e. it's normally used to open the default terminal), which is bound to Meta+T.
This command is easily changeable using gsettings, and you could change it to either

mate-terminal --maximize or
mate-terminal --full-screen

The first one will launch MATE terminal leaving MATE's top bar and the terminal window's decorations visible, while the second one will launch it "truly" full-screen. You can try both and decide which you prefer by running the commands in MATE terminal before changing the command.
Once you've decided, assuming you picked mate-terminal --maximize, to change the command:
gsettings set org.mate.Marco.keybinding-commands command-4 'mate-terminal --maximize'

If you're able to get someone to create a custom Ctrl+Alt+T shortcut for you using the GUI / for those that could do this using the GUI, below is the (preferrable I guess) method to to create a custom Ctrl+Alt+T shortcut using the GUI.


Click on "Menu" on MATE's top bar
Start typying "Keyboard Shortcuts" - click on "Keyboard Shortcuts"
Click on "Add"
Fill the "Name" field with whatever you want (say "MATE terminal") and the "Command" field with mate-terminal --maximize / mate-terminal --full-screen, then click on "Apply"
Your custom shortcut will be listed at the end below "Custom Shortcuts"; double-click on "Disabled" on the right-hand side
Hit Ctrl+Alt+T
You'll be warned that the Ctrl+Alt+T is already in use for the "Run a terminal" shortcut; click on "Reassign"
Close the window


